# Eigenvalues of a symmetric block matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

I have a $ m \times m$ matrix, $A$, of the following form:

$$A=\left( \begin{array} {c,c} A' \quad \vec{\delta} \\ \vec{\delta}^T \quad \varepsilon \end{array} \right)$$

wher $\vec{\delta}$ is a $(m-1) \times 1 $ column vector of $\delta$'s.
$A'$ is a $(m-1) \times (m-1)$ matrix of the following form:

$$
A'
=
b J_{m-1} + (a-b) I_{m-1}.
$$

Here $J_{m-1}$ is a $(m-1) \times (m-1)$ matrix of all one's and $I_{m-1}$ is the $(m-1) \times (m-1)$ identity matrix Hence $A'$ is a matrix with all $a$'s on the diagonal and all $b$'s off-diagonals.

I would like to compute the eigenvalues of $A$. What's the best way to compute these eigenvalues?

Comment: What have you tried? What about when $m=2$? How about $m=3$? Is there a pattern? Perhaps some kind of inductive argument?

Comment: I have calculated that $a-b$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $m-2$. I am wondering if it is possible to calculate the other two eigenvalues. For $m=5$, Mathematica gives somewhat complicated expressions for these eigenvalues.

Comment: The expressions shouldn't be too complicated : indeed, using a C.A.S., I found that the characteristic polynomial is $(a-b-x)^{m-2}(x^2-(a+e+(m-2)b)x+(ae+(m-2)be-(m-1)d^2))$. But I have no idea of a proof.